# How do I pass a class to new indirectly in clojure

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I have a clojure class (a namespace with a `(:gen-class)` clause).
I then need to pass a constructed object to a java function.
this works

```
 (java_function (my-clojure-class.))
```

However, if I need to refer to the class indirectly, that runs into some problems
because `new` does not evaluate its argument. I am able to get the desired result by using

```
(let [my-class my-clojure-class]
     (java_function 
         (eval `(new ~(symbol (. my-class getName))))))
```

While this works it feels clunky. Is there a cleaner way or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [newInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) method to create a new instance from `my-class` that is of type [java.lang.Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

```clj
(let [my-class my-clojure-class]
  (java_function (.newInstance my-class)))
```